# Spring Security and OneLogin Token Expiration

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, onelogin

I am trying to configure an authentication flow in Spring Boot using OneLogin SSO. I can successfully authenticate, create a JWT token, and redirect to my frontend app.

However, I am not certain of the next steps. When my JWT token expires, is the appropriate course to clear my security context and then to redirect to OneLogin again and reconfirm my authentication? Right now, as far as I can tell, Spring's security context represents one moment in time and I can't figure out how to refresh it against my SSO provider to ensure the user is still authenticated.

Comment: Do you have some kind of refresh token so that you don't have to redirect when the token expires?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I do, yes. However, once that token expires, I still will need to reconfirm with OneLogin that my user is authenticated with them. The only way I can think to do this is to clear the context and somehow redirect, but it seems a bit ungainly.